# Проблема с кодировкой при импорте из CSV

Tags: php, кодировка, csv, импорт

Есть CSV таблица со столбцами примерно такого вида: `id;sku;Название;Категория`.
Таблица сохранена в формате UTF-8.

Далее я пытаюсь сделать массив (название столбца => какое-то значение), вот код:

```
$f = fopen(public_path('/path/file.csv'), 'r');
$columns = fgetcsv($f, null, ';');
$test = [];

foreach($columns as $key => &$column)
{
   $test[$column] = 0;
}

var_dump($test);
```

Получаю вот такой результат:

```
array(4) {
    ["﻿id"] => int(0)
    ["sku"] => int(0)
    ["Название"] => int(0)
    ["Категория"] => int(0)
}
```

Вроде бы все получилось, но если обратиться к **первому** элементу по ключу `$test['id']` *(обращаю внимание, именно к первому)*, то получаю ошибку `Undefined index: id`. Далее я решил преобразовать массив в JSON и увидел такую картину:

```
{
   "\ufeffid": 0,
   "sku": 0,
   "\u041d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435": 0,
   "\u041a\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0433\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f": 0
}
```

Если же использовать `json_encode` c опцией `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, то все отображается нормально:

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "sku": 0,
   "Название": 0,
   "Категория": 0
}
```

Понятное дело, что в тут скорее всего дело в кодировке, но все равно не понимаю как исправить эту ситуацию. Почему только с первый элементом происходит такая беда, а остальные ключи записываются нормально? Буду очень признателен за ваши подсказки, ответы и примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54145162/9339546), для решения этой проблемы нужно удалить BOM заголовок. Переписал свой код таким образом:

```
$f = fopen(public_path('/path/file.csv'), 'r');
$columns = fgetcsv($f, null, ';');

$tempZeroCol = trim(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $this->columns[0]));
if(!empty($tempZeroCol)) {
    $this->columns[0] = $tempZeroCol;
}

$test = [];
foreach($columns as $key => &$column)
{
    $test[$column] = 0;
}

var_dump($test);
```